# Error on the site - session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>

Tags: php, session

My site was working fine, but suddently today i saw the site down and no one page is showing up. I found the error in database table "error_logs" that is -

```
session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: open(/tmp/sess_8ef98c4df344123c0cb28dc727e70664, O_RDWR) failed: Read-only file system (30)
```

I can't understand this issue and how to solve it.

Comment: We really need more information.  What platform is your site implemented on?

Comment: The site is developed in PHP, and hosted on Linux server...

Answer (score 0):

A read-only file system usually indicates that **your hard drive has failed**. Do you have any kind of access to your server? (e.g. FTP, SSH)

To verify this if you have SSH (and root) access, try creating a file, and checking the logs for error messages:

```
touch /tmp/test.txt
dmesg | tail
```

If you have FTP/SFTP access, try uploading a file and seeing if it works.

Comment: Thanks for reply,
I have an access of cPanel so i have created a file called "testing.html" and it can be accessible from the browser.

Comment: It sounds like you're on a shared hosting platform. You should then check with your web host if this is the case, as "read-only file system" can be either a drive failure or a configuration change on their side.

Comment: okay,
I feel there might be the PHP configuration issue on server, so i'll contact the hosting support regarding this issue,
Thanks for the help...!